# Configure API gateway with managed Instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, api-gateway

I want to use the Google API gateway to add authentication for my APIs hosted in compute engine. I do not see any documentation to configure a managed instance group as the backend service for API gateway, how do I do that ?

Comment: API gateway can only forward request to HTTP endpoint. A load balancer in front of your MIG could held you ;)

Comment: My plan was to have this : loadbalancer -> API Gateway ->  MIG, so if add a LB between gateway and MIG, it will be loadbalancer -> API Gateway -> Loadbalancer -> MIG , note that the API will ultimately be publicly accessible at say api.xx.com. How do you suggest I expose the APIs ?

Comment: I think you have no choice. I don't see another possible design

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, got to work on it only this week. I created an internal loadbalancer for the API gateway to point to and the gateway is complaining that it cannot forward to ip addresses. Also read that gateway can forward only to public accessible urls. If the LB has to be public accessible then there is no point using gateway as someone can access the LB directly anyway.  All I want to do is secure my api endpoint ( api.xx.com ). I looked at IAP but that requires beyondcorp premium and is mainly targeted for securing websites and not APIs. What is the best way of securing API ?

Comment: Some additional info. The api endpoint will be accessed from mobile apps and I use firebase Auth on the mobile app. I have been using FB Auth tokens to secure the API using API gateway with CloudRun backend. Now I want to replace cloudrun with Compute Engine Manage Instance group